# Easy way migrate data from MySql to Derby (JAVADB)?

Tags: mysql, derby, database-migration, javadb

I have to migrate my database from MySql to Derby. However, I am facing a problem, that it is not possible just to create sql dump and import in JavaDB. Is there an easy way, a tool or something that I can use? or should I do everything by hand?

Danke

Answer (score 1):

One good way, is to use [DdlUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/). 
with this, you can export a database schema from one database and create it in another.
This is the [MySQL page](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/databases/mysql.html).